# User agent string

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, user-agent

```
Browser Name: Microsoft Internet Explorer

Browser Version: 4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

What the exact version of embeded browser? I see `4.0`, but in brackets there is `MSIE 7.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`MSIE 7.0` indicates that the specific version is Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0.**

You have to read the whole string, not just the first part. I'm pretty sure that the first part actually says "Mozilla/4.0", which just means that the browser is compatible with Mozilla 4.0. This is reported for historical reasons and to address issues arising from the widespread practice of "browser sniffing".
[A question was just asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125438/why-chrome-and-ie-put-mozilla-5-0-in-the-userstring-they-used-to-send-request-to) about why Google Chrome and Internet Explorer put "Mozilla" in their user agent string.

You should also read the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463915/what-does-it-mean-when-ie-reports-two-versions-in-useragent), which explain why IE reports two different version numbers in its user agent string.

Comment: I just find out more explanation that seem's legit: http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/internet-explorer/485301-ie-8-actually-mozilla-product.html#post1776436

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the exact output of the user agent string by pasting it into http://www.useragentstring.com/ so it looks like IE8 in compatibility mode IE7

Answer (score 0):

MSIE 7.0 -> Internet Explorer 7.0

And here is the exact meaning of all information you have:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It must be `Mozilla/4.0`: "For historical reasons, Internet Explorer identifies itself as a Mozilla 4.0 browser."